# pandas dataframe string formatting (access a given column)

Tags: python, string, pandas, formatting, string-formatting

I try to use new-style formatting to display the entry at a given/specified column:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(7, size=(2, 2)), columns=['a', 'b'])
c = df.iloc[0, :] # get row number 0
print("Here is {one[0]} and {two}".format(one=c, two=c['b'])) # Ok
```

But I'd like to do it as follows:

```
print("Here is {one['a']} and {two}".format(one=c, two=c['b'])) ## Unfortunately KeyError: "'a'"
```

Is it possible to do that and how?

Comment: Why would you like to do it as you proposed?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The point is it's easier to specify directly one column by name instead of remembering that column number 6 is the one that I'm interested in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can remove `''` in `one['a']`:

```
print("Here is {one[a]} and {two}".format(one=c, two=c['b']))
Here is 3 and 6
```

Comment: Neat! I would have never thought of removing the extra quotes in the format string!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` to get the value of column `a`.

```
print("Here is {one} and {two}".format(one=c.loc['a'], two=c['b']))
Here is 3 and 6
```

You can also do it this way.

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)

n = 0  # Get the first row.    
>>> "{row[a]} and {row[b]} makes {row[sum]}".format(row=df.iloc[n, :])
'3 and 6 makes 9'
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander. Thanks but no, your answer doesn't address my question: it's just a variation on `two=c['b']` while I just want to specify the correct column in the format string.

Comment: Accessing the data point is similar, the difference is that the data should go in the `format()` section and any formatting applied to it should go in the brackets, eg. {one: %.2f}.  Although technically possible, you should not specify your data in the string itself.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Why shouldn't one not specify the data field in the string itself? The doc you linked to doesn't do this recommendation. I thought that the possibility of specifying data fields in the string is even one of the most interesting points of the new-style formatting.

Comment: You use either positional arguments (e.g. `{0}, {2}`, etc. or named arguments (e.g. `{one}, {two}`, etc).  You then specify the formatting of that data, eg. `""Here is {one:.2f} and {two:%}"`.  Here is PEP 3101 which explains in detail the rational for the change. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: Alexander: In this PEP, you can also read a whole section about **compound field names** so why do you recommend to abandon this feature??

Comment: I am not recommending the abandonment of compound field names.  I am promoting "simple is better than complex", "beautiful is better than ugly" and "readability counts".