# pandas dataframe string formatting with nested arguments (access specified column)

Tags: python, pandas, nested, arguments, string-formatting

This is a follow-up to [how to access a given column in string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632328/pandas-dataframe-string-formatting-access-a-given-column).

Instead of

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(7, size=(2, 2)), columns=['a', 'b'])
c = df.iloc[0, :] # get 0-th row
print("Here is {one[a]} and {two}".format(one=c, two=c['b'])) # Ok (see linked question)
```

I'd like to be able to refer to the column in a nested argument but it doesn't work:

```
print("Here is {one[{col}]} and {two}".format(col='a', one=c, two=c['b'])) # Problem: KeyError: '{col}'
```

It should work but it didn't. Any hint?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote but anyway ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got that error due to nested substitution with `format`. You could mix `%` and `format` for that case...

```
print(("Here is {one[%(col)s]} and {two}" % {'col':'a'}).format(one=c, two=c['b']))

Here is 3 and 6
```

Comment: Your mix formatting style works. From the doc, this kind of nested replacement should have worked while only using `format`  ...  Sorry, I'm wrong. After careful reading, only the **format specifier** can get nested replacement fields!!

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in my reply to the linked question, that is not how you should be referencing your data.

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

> str.format(*args, **kwargs) Perform a string formatting operation. The
>   string on which this method is called can contain literal text or
>   replacement fields delimited by braces {}. Each replacement field
>   contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the
>   name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy of the string where each
>   replacement field is replaced with the string value of the
>   corresponding argument.
>
> `>>> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2) 'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'`

It is best to be explicit in your code about the data.

```
>>> print("Here is {one} and {two}".format(one=c['a'], two=c['b']))
Here is 3 and 6
```

or...

```
col1 = 'a'
col2 = 'b'
>>> print("Here is {one} and {two}".format(one=c[col1], two=c[col2]))
Here is 3 and 6
```

even better...

```
col1 = 'a'
col2 = 'b'

n = 0  # Get the first row.
one, two = df.ix[n, [col1, col2]]
>>> print("Here is {one} and {two}".format(one=one, two=two))
Here is 3 and 6
```

Given that a Series supports `__getattr__` under the hood, you can also access the results indirectly using dot notation or like a dictionary lookup.

```
row = df.loc[n]

>>> print("Here is {row.a} and {row.b}".format(row=row))
Here is 3 and 6
```

Although it is always safer to access data with brackets incase any column name clashes with an existing Series property or method.

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)

# Safe method.
>>> print("{row[a]} and {row[b]} make {row[sum]}".format(row=row))
    3 and 6 make 9

# Unsafe method.
print("{row.a} and {row.b} make {row.sum}".format(row=row))
3 and 6 make <bound method Series.sum of a      3
b      6
sum    9
Name: 0, dtype: int64>
```

Comment: I thought that it (the ability to access data fields) was a feature of the new-style formatting?

Comment: Hi Alexander. I agree with you. The mixed format is really ugly even if it answers the question. As a side note: the 'even better' you propose is not always the best way as sometimes I just need to display small parts of a very lengthy row.

Comment: Really depends on your use case and readability.  You want to make things as simple as possible for others to understand.